# Curly braces don't preserve capitals

Tags: capitalization, jabref

First of all, thanks to everybody who posts on this site. This is my first time asking a question, since I have always been able to figure out my problems before thanks to others' questions + answers.

I am using JabRef and TeXworks.

**Using curly braces doesn't work to preserve capitals in my references** and I'm looking for a solution.

My preference would be a solution that simply allows me to use the curly braces as they are intended.

I have tried all versions of curly braces I could think of or find:

i. {Report on the Status of B.C. First Nations Languages 2010}
ii. Report on the {S}tatus of {B}.{C}. {F}irst {N}ations {L}anguages 2010
iii. {Report on the {S}tatus of {B}.{C}. {F}irst {N}ations {L}anguages 2010}
iv. Report on the {{S}}tatus of {{B}}.{{C}}. {{F}}irst {{N}}ations {{L}}anguages 2010

I have also tried to change the preferences in JabRef to store certain fields with braces around capital letters, and this didn't work.

To generate the references in my document I typed:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{ReferencesJabRef}
```

Here's an example that's giving me problems:

```
Author = Hannah Amrhein and Suzanne Gessner  
Title = Report on the Status of B.C. First Nations Languages 2010  
Institution = First Peoples’ Heritage, Language and Culture Council  
Year = 2010  
Bibtex Key = FirstPeoples2010  
Address = Brentwood Bay, B.C.  
URL = http://www.fpcc.ca/language/status-report/
```

And it prints like this:

> Amrhein, H. & Gessner, S. (2010). Report on the status of b.c. first nations languages 2010 (Tech. Rep.). Brentwood Bay, B.C.: First peoples Heritage, Language and Culture Council. Retrieved from http://www.fpcc.ca/language/status-report/

The problems are:

- In the title, I'd at least like "B.C." and "First Nations" capitalized.
- For the institution, the word "Peoples" should also be capitalized.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you using *double* curly braces to encase the contents of the `title` field? Please consider posting an actual bib entry that's giving you trouble.

Comment: Just to be clear: in the case of the 'Title' line, it should look like: `Title = {{Report} on the {Status} of {B.C.} {First} {Nations} {Languages} 2010},`.  Your question makes it look like JabRef hides the braces by default; you can open your `.bib` file in a plain text editor to make sure JabRef is saving your changes correctly.  (Normally it would, I'm sure, but it doesn't hurt to check when things aren't working out.)   Also: don't forget that after you change your `.bib` file, the changes won't be reflected in your document until another run or `bibtex`+`latex`+`latex` has been completed.