# Why aren't double curly braces around the title field of a bib entry preserving capitalization?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I have stumbled upon a peculiar situation in one of my latest documents: even though all titles in the BibTeX file are surrounded by double curly braces (all the way from the beginning to the end, which is Mendeley's default behavior), the `ieee` bibliography style still manages to override that with sentence capitalization.

Here is one of the entries, exported from Mendeley:

```
@article{huang2011short,
author = {Huang, H K},
doi = {10.1016/j.ejrad.2010.05.007},
issn = {1872-7727},
journal = {European journal of radiology},
keywords = {20th Century,21st Century,Financing,Government,Government Agencies,Government Agencies: history,Government: history,History,Humans,Medical Informatics,Medical Informatics: history,Radiology Information Systems,Radiology Information Systems: history,United States},
month = may,
number = {2},
pages = {163--76},
pmid = {21440396},
title = {{Short history of PACS. Part I: USA.}},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0720048X1000207X},
volume = {78},
year = {2011}
}
```

And a minimal version of my document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}

\bibliography{../bib/library.bib}

\begin{document}
  \mainmatter
  \include{./matter}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using a custom command in TeXstudio that cleans auxiliary files, builds "matter.tex" from other sources and then performs "Build & View" on the main document. The outcome is just as if there were single curly braces around the title:

[image: Outcome of compilation]

There happens to be a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162170/curly-braces-dont-preserve-capitals) with a similar symptom, but it was left unattended from both ends (and I am not using JabRef). All my other search efforts on this matter only show when to use additional pairs of curly braces where we wish to preserve all capitalization, which is supposed to already happen at this point. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The double braces don't provide the required protection. Use

```
title = {Short history of {PACS}. {Part} {I}: {USA}.},
```

[image]

I believe that Biber is removing a pair of braces around the entire field, assuming that it was added by some software that's trying to be too smart. Capitalization of titles should be left to the bibliographic style, not forced. If the external software such as Mendeley or Web of Science is not able to put braces where necessary for maintaining correct capitalization *where needed*, it's a problem of that software. Checking items for correctness should never be overlooked.

Comment: Indeed, that worked for me. But still, why is it that a full encapsulation of the title with double curly brackets would not have any effect? Some [Mendeley-related issues](http://feedback.mendeley.com/forums/4941-general/suggestions/469422-add-an-option-to-disable-double-curly-brackets-aro) suggest that capitalization should have been forced.

Comment: Also note that as egreg does here, only those words that should not be changed, should be protected. It us the journal that decides what type or general casing they use not the author or the author of the cited work.

Comment: @daleif I understand the concern completely, and I wouldn't keep my bib file as it is before submitting. It's just that I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior.

Comment: @E_net4 My impression is that it is a feature of `biblatex` because the same happens with Biber.

Comment: Right, all works as expected if I don't use `biblatex`. It seems to be canceling the effect out.

Comment: This issue ought to be reported to the maintainer(s) of the `biblatex` package.

Comment: Probably the software can't tell. I think you have to check auto-generated entries always. It seems popular to add extra curly brackets, though I think it is wrong. The software should refrain since adding them where needed is less work than removing them everywhere else. [This is an argument I've won at least once with one such instance of software. Unfortunately, they keep coming up with new variations rather than leaving well enough alone. So I keep bug-reporting the regressions.)

Comment: I *think* this has to do with [`\bbx@colon@search`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/blob/master/ieee.bbx#L466) which is a `biblatex-ieee` macro. If one uses only `biblatex`'s on-board features with `\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\bbx@colon@search\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}` the case protection is as expected. I believe `\bbx@colon@search` gets rid of the extra group of braces.